# Changing CSS properties of a navigation bar on click using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on creating a website for an assignment, and I have a horizontal navigation bar created using an ordered list. Each list item is a link to another page on the site, and I'm trying to change the background colour as well as the text colour of the list items when on click, when active. I know it's much easier to use CSS, which I can do, but it's recommended that I use JQuery, which I'm nothing short of useless with. How can I do this? Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
   <li><a href="roster.html">Roster</a></li>
   <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
   <li><a href="documentation.html">Documentation</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline;
}

.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px #000000;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 23px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: What would you like it to do onClick?

Comment: SO requires that you try it first, than ask questions when you have problems.

Comment: Since you seem to be needing a push in the right direction, check out the documentation on `.click()` from the Jquery website. This is pretty simple so you should be able to figure it out. If not, come back with what you've tried and we can better help you from there. http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @JoshC Edited to specify. Sorry about that, I'm looking to change the background colour and text colour of the link.

Comment: Why is it recommended that you use jQuery? This is definitely a job for CSS `:active` states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you started, though it's a little unclear what you're trying to achieve.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/k4LbD/1/)

```
$('ul.nav > li').click(function(){
    $(this).children('a').toggleClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('li').children('a').removeClass('active');
});
```

In this instance, I would only suggest using jQuery for click functions.

As (@Nick M) points out, you should use CSS for the rest.

---

**EDIT..**

I may have misunderstood you, I believe you are just looking for the [**`:active`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) pseudo class.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/k4LbD/2/)

```
.nav a:active {
    /* style */
}
```